# NSNotificationCenter: pass Notification between 2 classes

Tags: iphone, xcode, message, nsnotifications

i have 2 classes.

class1 gets some information through the net. when one of these informations comes, class1 has to send a notification to class2.

i understood it so that i have to put

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:at"anyUserNotification" object:class2];
```

into class1

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:atselector(anyInteraction:) name:dontKnowTheSense object:dunno2];
```

have i understood the object:class2 in the postnotification right ?
if yes: is it possible to make an anonymious notification, so that the sending class must not know, which and how many classes are listening ?
or - at least i think so, have i understood the whole notification incorrect ?

besides the notification i dont need to pass any data, but in one case it would be helpful to pass an enum

so, could anybody please help me ?

btw: i cant find a way to post an at on this windows-pc and i dont know, why it did not indent the code, i  think i made 4 spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object is not a mandatory argument you can set it to nil or the object sending the notification message.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:notificationSenderOrNil];
```

When listening you can filter to only do something for notification sent by a specific sender.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sel) name:@"NotificationName" object:notificationSenderOrNil];
```

And you can pass your data in a dictionnary with userInfo: argument.

Is it Ok with that ?

Comment: i think so, sounds understandable